# Is there a way to make Class[key] work to extract from a static container?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to build a class that maintains an internal list of all objects of that class and can look them up by ID. While I could use `myClass.get(objectID)` to get the objects, I would really prefer to use `myClass[objectID]` but this throws `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. Is there any permutation of the sample case below that would work?

```py
class Bucket(object):
    bucket = set()
    
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        Bucket.bucket.add(self)
    
    def get(id):
        return Bucket.__getitem__(None, id)
    
    def __getitem__(self, id):
        for i in Bucket.bucket:
            if i.id == id:
                return i.name
        return None

b = Bucket("foo", "bar")

print(1, Bucket.get("foo"))
print(2, b["foo"])
print(3, Bucket["foo"])
```

```
1 bar
2 bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{snip}\bucketTest.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(3, Bucket["foo"])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

---

**EDIT**

With a hint in the direction of metaclasses, I've come up with this. As I have honestly never stumbled across them before, I have to ask: am I doing this right? Am I missing some fundamental bit, or is this vaguely correct? How could I improve it?

```py
class MetaBucket(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls.bucket = set()
    
    def __getitem__(cls, key):
        for i in cls.bucket:
            if i.id == key:
                return i.name

class Bucket(metaclass = MetaBucket):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        Bucket.bucket.add(self)

b = Bucket("foo", "bar")

print(3, Bucket["foo"])
```

Comment: This must be implemented on the *metaclass*, which is what would control `MyClass[key]`, on the other hand, `MyClass.__getitem__` controls `my_instance[key]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OK, cool, I had absolutely no idea that metaclasses were a thing. I don't think I can put code blocks in a comment like this, but I'm going to edit the question with what I've got to see if I'm doing this at all correctly.

Comment: BTW, using a `set` simply to iterate over it **completely defeats the purpose** of a `set` object. Use a `dict` instead, mapping id's to the object, then just do something like `return cls.buket[key].name`

Comment: RE - Using a dict instead of a set: Honestly? Yes. Yes it does make more sense. D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your **EDIT** that uses a metaclass, I'd suggest using a `dict` instead of a `set` for the `bucket` attribute since it makes things easier and more succinct:

```
class MetaBucket(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls.bucket = {}

    def __getitem__(cls, id):
        return cls.bucket[id]

    def __setitem__(cls, id, name):
        cls.bucket[id] = name


class Bucket(metaclass=MetaBucket):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.bucket[id] = name


b = Bucket("foo", "bar")
print(3, Bucket["foo"])  # -> 3 bar
print(4, Bucket["nonesuch"])  # -> KeyError: 'nonesuch'
```

Comment: Yes, using a dict does make sense. Thank you!